# Invalid key name for REG ADD on some PCs

Tags: windows-registry

The following commands work on my PC:

```
reg add Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa /v everyoneincludesanonymous /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters /v restrictnullsessaccess /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

However, on some machines it responds with:

```
ERROR: Invalid key name.
Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.
```

I'm unsure as to what is different and how I could handle this.

Comment: I would try removing the Computer\ part.

Comment: Ill try this soon ty

Comment: Forgot to tell you that that worked. Some PCs need \\%computername%\HKEY...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the help for `REG.EXE ADD /?` the format of the registry path must start with either a computer name or one of five root key names:

```
REG ADD KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve] [/t Type] [/s Separator] [/d Data] [/f]

  KeyName  [\\Machine\]FullKey
           Machine  Name of remote machine - omitting defaults to the
                    current machine. Only HKLM and HKU are available on remote
                    machines.
           FullKey  ROOTKEY\SubKey
           ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
           SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.
```

If your KeyName value begins with `\\` it will be treated as a computer name, otherwise REG.EXE expects one of the ROOTKEY values. Since your command does not begin the path with `\\` REG.EXE expects one of the ROOTKEY values. Because `Computer` is not one of those five values, you get the error:

> ERROR: Invalid key name.
>   Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.

You can fix your command by either removing the leading `Computer\` from the path:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa /v everyoneincludesanonymous /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Or by specifying the computer name using the leading slashes:

```
reg add \\Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa /v everyoneincludesanonymous /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

**Note:** This assumes your computer name is actually "Computer". If it isn't provide its actual name.

Comment: I tried this but still I have faced same "ERROR: Invalid key name.". Then I tried "HKCU" instead of "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" then it is worked for me. This is the sample "REG ADD HKCU\Software\SS64 /v Sample /d "some test data"" which is worked for me and I got from following this https://www.urtech.ca/2018/08/solved-command-line-script-to-add-or-delete-a-registry-entry/.